# Installing Theano with GPU on Windows 8.1 (Python 3.4). nvcc fatal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, python-3.4, theano, theano-cuda

I'm trying to set up Theano to use GPU, but I keep getting the same error when importing theano in python environment:

> nvcc fatal   : Could not set up the environment for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio using 'd:/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0/VC/bin//../../VC/bin/amd64/vcvars64.bat'

---

I have a `.theanorc` file in my `C:\Users\Denis\` folder:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
compiler_bindir=D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe
```

I also have a Vistual Studio 2012 installed on the `D:\` disk. CUDA 8 is installed in the default location.

In my `PATH` environment variable, apart from CUDA and other env vars, I have the following:

```
d:\Anaconda3\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\;d:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64;d:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe;
```

I use Anaconda and Python 3.4. My Anaconda folder is located in `D:\Anaconda3\`.

I've also set up this environment variables:

```
VCINSTALLDIR = d:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC

VSINSTALLDIR = d:\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
```

---

I keep getting the same error when importing `theano`.

Could you please help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?